# Why is the ^ character used in this ClojureScript snippet?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, re-frame

In the clojurescript re-frame todomvc application we find the following snippet in the [todomvc.views](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/master/examples/todomvc/src/todomvc/views.cljs)  namespace.

```
(defn todo-list
  [visible-todos]
  [:ul.todo-list
   (for [todo  @visible-todos]
     ^{:key (:id todo)} [todo-item todo])])
```

Although I have read the Clojure chapter on [metadata](http://clojure.org/reference/metadata) I don't quite understand the purpose of:

```
^{:key
```

in the snippet above. Please explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:key` is what React needs when you have many items, so that they can be unique within the group. But the latest version of React does not need these keys. So if you use the latest versions of reframe / Reagent, just try without the `:key` metadata.

This metadata is equivalent to placing `:key` within the component. So for example what you have is equivalent to:

```
[todo-item {:key (:id todo)} todo]
```

Using the metadata approach is a convenience, which must in some cases be easier than the 'first key in props passed to the component' approach.

Here's more [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446913/reagent-react-clojurescript-warning-every-element-in-a-seq-should-have-a-unique).

Comment: Interesting for the author of re-frame as well !  - Just found it in Reagent tutorial ... " The ^{:key item} part above isn’t really necessary in this simple example, but attaching a unique key to every item in a dynamically generated list of components is good practice, and helps React to improve performance for large lists. "

Answer (score 1):

`^{:key (:id todo)} [todo-item todo]` would be equivalent to `(with-meta [todo-item todo] {:key (:id todo)})`, see  https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-meta

Reagent uses this to generate the corresponding react component with a key. Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. here is the explanation: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html