# Lazy vs Eager Seq of Reagent Components

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I had the following code:

```
(ns my.app
  (:require [reagent.core :as r]))

(def data (r/atom {}))

(defn child-component
  [group-title group-data]
  some-hiccup)

(defn parent-component []
  [:div
    (for [[group-title group-data] @data]
      [child-component group-title group-data])])

(js/window.addEventListener "load"
  #(r/render [parent-component]
     (js/document.getElementById "some-id"))
  false)
```

It was exhibiting unexpected behavior: when I made certain updates to `data`, Reagent would call the components' renderers but not update the UI, while other changes would cause `parent-component` to be *remounted* rather than simply updated and each `child-component` to be rendered from scratch.  In no case would it minimally update existing components the way React is supposed to.

I guessed that the problem had something to do with `for`, so I played around with some alternatives.  I tried wrapping `for` in `doall`, tried coercing the seq into a vector, and even tried wrapping `for` in a `let` and moving the `@data` deref to the `let` binding vector just in case the problem was related to my derefing the `r/atom` in the `for` binding vector.  None of those changes made any difference.

Since I know in advance the keys of the map stored in `data`, I was able to try the following, and it worked:

```
(defn parent-component []
  [:div
    (let [data-map @data]
      (list
        [child-component :title-1 (:title-1 data-map)]
        [child-component :title-2 (:title-2 data-map)]))])
```

Although this solved my problem in this case, it's unsatisfactory as a general solution, because you won't always know the shape of data that will be stored in your `r/atom`.  So, finally I discovered a solution that works for the general case:

```
(defn parent-component []
  (reduce
    (fn [prev [group-title group-data]]
      (conj prev [child-component group-title group-data]))
    [:div]
    @data))
```

So my problem is solved, but I don't understand why.  If the problem was just that I needed to make the original seq eager, why didn't `doall` do the trick?  Either I'm making some really stupid mistake, or there's something about the inner workings of Reagent that I don't understand.

**Note:** I'm also managing the `r/atom` in an idiosyncratic way, which relates to the comment I made above about how Reagent behaved differently depending on *how* I updated the `r/atom`.  However, I am not sure if that would be relevant to my general question about using `reduce` vs `doall`.  Let me know if it is, and I'll provide some details on that.

****Edit****

I figured it out!  The problem was my use of `:key`, which I neglected to mention above.  The original `parent-component` looked like this:

```
(defn parent-component []
  [:div
    (for [[group-title group-data] @data]
      ^{:key (gensym)}
      [child-component group-title group-data])])
```

Maybe this is something about React that I don't understand, but it seems that you shouldn't use `gensym` to generate the `:key`.  I changed to the following, and everything works fine:

```
(defn parent-component []
  [:div
    (for [[group-title group-data] @data]
      ^{:key group-title}
      [child-component group-title group-data])])
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/33458370/597473. It explains the role of `^{:key...}`.

Comment: That discussion doesn't seem to explain why I would have a problem with `(gensym)`.  I do understand why and when `^{:key ...}` is used, but if the only requirement is that each key be unique, I don't understand why `(gensym)` wouldn't do the trick. Is it because `(gensym)` gets called again each time Reagent calls the rendering function, thus leading Reagent to believe it's a distinct element?

Comment: I guess this might be the case. You can replace `(gensym)` with your wrapper function that will log to console every time its called before it returns the result of `(gensym)` to verify.