# re-frame: adding a new map element in nested vector

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

I have this structure (ordered map) in my "db" with the keyword ":questions":

```
{:33 {:question "one", :id 33, :answers [{:id 22, :question_id 33, :answer "one", :correct false}
                                              {:id 4,  :question_id 33, :answer "two", :correct false}]}},
{:39 {:question "two", :id 39, :answers []}},
{:41 {:question "three", :id 41, :answers [{:id 29, :question_id 41, :answer "one", :correct false}
                                                {:id 35, :question_id 41, :answer "two", :correct true}]}}
```

I can add a new question in the event handler "re-frame/reg-event-db" adding:

```
(assoc-in db [:questions (:id response)] new-map-stuff)
```

but I don't know how to add a map in the ":answers" key. Besides, I'm afraid that I'm rendering all the questions every time I'm adding a new answer.

I read about the "path" interceptor (kind of "update-in"), but I can't find an example about how to use it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it just like in plain clojure, using `update-in`.  First start at the Clojure CheatSheet:

http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html

or the ClojureScript version:  http://cljs.info

Look at the docs for `update-in`:  https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update-in

You need 2 componenents

1. A path to navigate the the site of the mutation
2. A function to perform the mutation *given the point from (1)*.

You didn't fully specify your data.  I'm assuming it looks like this:

```
(def db {:questions [
           {:33 {:question "one", :id 33,
                 :answers  [{:id 22, :question_id 33, :answer "one", :correct false}
                            {:id  4, :question_id 33, :answer "two", :correct false}]}},
           {:39 {:question "two", :id 39, :answers []}},
           {:41 {:question "three", :id 41,
                 :answers  [{:id 29, :question_id 41, :answer "one", :correct false}
                            {:id 35, :question_id 41, :answer "two", :correct true}]}}]})
```

I'll make up a new `answer` map to add:

```
(def new-answer {:id 42, :question_id 442, :answer "The Ultimate", :correct false})
```

This code shows the process in pieces.

```
  (let [submap       (get-in db [:questions 0 :33 :answers])
        modified     (conj submap new-answer)
        final-answer (update-in db [:questions 0 :33 :answers] conj new-answer)   ]
```

First the navigation to get `submap`:

```
submap => 
[{:id 22, :question_id 33, :answer "one", :correct false}
 {:id  4, :question_id 33, :answer "two", :correct false}]
```

And the way you add the new answer:

```
modified => 
[{:id 22, :question_id  33, :answer "one", :correct false}
 {:id  4, :question_id  33, :answer "two", :correct false}
 {:id 42, :question_id 442, :answer "The Ultimate", :correct false}]
```

And putting it all together into one operation:

```
final-answer => 
{:questions
 [{:33
   {:question "one",
    :id 33,
    :answers
    [{:id 22, :question_id  33, :answer "one", :correct false}
     {:id  4, :question_id  33, :answer "two", :correct false}
     {:id 42, :question_id 442, :answer "The Ultimate", :correct false}]}}
  {:39 {:question "two", :id 39, :answers []}}
  {:41
   {:question "three",
    :id 41,
    :answers
    [{:id 29, :question_id 41, :answer "one", :correct false}
     {:id 35, :question_id 41, :answer "two", :correct true}]}}]}
```

All of this works identically in ClojureScript as in Clojure.

Don't worry about using the `path` interceptor.  I think it confuses things more than it helps.  And don't worry about render speed unless:

1. You have it working and tested and know it is right.
2. You have measured the render speed and can document that there is a problem *and* the amount you need to speed up.
3. For long lists of things look at the `key` metadata you can add to each list element for Reagent. See:  [Reagent React Clojurescript Warning: Every element in a seq should have a unique :key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446913/reagent-react-clojurescript-warning-every-element-in-a-seq-should-have-a-unique)

---

***Update***

Note that `submap` and `modified` are shown ***only for demonstration purposes*** to show pieces of how `update-in` works.  The `update-in` expression is the only thing you would actually include in your code. Also, note that the `update-in` **only uses** `db` and `new-answer`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just to notice, in the dotest block the final call is:

        final-answer (update-in db [:questions 0 :33 :answers] conj **modified**)

right?

Comment: No. We are using `conj` to append `new-answer` onto the end of the existing `:answers` array. Study `update` & `update-in`. The path that finds `modified` silently inserts a reference to the destination as the first arg to the function `conj`. The `new-answer` becomes the 2nd arg to `conj`. The result of `conj` is then stitched back into place deep in the hierarchy.